# Including a self-referential model in activerecord and selecting based on included model from both

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

Apologies for the rather confusing title, I'm finding it rather difficult to phrase this question properly.

I have a model, call it `Thing` that `has_many :related_things`, `has_many :associated_dates` and `has_many :assignments` (users assigned to things). I want to make a single query to select all associated dates from a `Thing` which a user is assigned to, as well as all associated dates from the related things.

At the moment, I have this which works for getting the associated dates which are directly assigned:

```
AssociatedDate.includes(:thing)
   .includes(:thing => :assignments)
   .where('assignments.user_id' => id)
```

However, my attempts to also load those dates that are related through `:related_things` are not loaded. The closest I've got is just including the `:related_things` in the query:

```
AssociatedDate.includes(:thing)
   .includes(:thing => [:assignments, :related_things])
   .where('assignments.user_id' => id)
```

But then I don't know where to go from there and on its own this does not have any effect on the outcome of the query. Is the select I want possible, and how would I go about doing it?

Comment: It's a very bad idea to call your model Date!!! It will override the Rails Date object and this will lead to strange circumstances!

Comment: Sorry, that's my simplification for posting the question, it's not called `Date` in the actual application :-) I'll update it to reflect this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `joins`. Have a look at the documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables).

Something like `AssociatedDate.joins(:thing).joins(:thing=>:related_thing)`